# protobuf.dll not found even though static linking is specified

Tags: cmake, dll, protocol-buffers, static-libraries

I have a static library `ppc2cpp_core.lib` which I want to link statically with protobuf. This library is in turn used by `ppc2cpp.exe`, which (hopefully) forms a standalone executable. I am using vcpkg for the protobuf library.

When I try to run it, I'm getting that `libprotobuf.dll` is missing. Looking at the cmake build logs, it looks pretty apparent to me that both `ppc2cpp_core.lib` and `ppc2cpp.exe` use static linking, and also the same configuration on linux is working (ldd does not show a dependency on libprotobuf.so)

`ppc2cpp_core.lib`:

```
[79/83] cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f ppc2cpp_core.lib && C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\llvm-ar.exe qc ppc2cpp_core.lib  CMakeFiles/ppc2cpp_core.dir/src/analysis/PpcdisAnalysis.cpp.obj [...a bunch of other object files...] && C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\LLVM-R~1.EXE ppc2cpp_core.lib && cd ."
```

`ppc2cpp.exe`

```
[82/83] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\CLANG_~1.EXE -fuse-ld=lld-link -nostartfiles -nostdlib -O3 -DNDEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrt -Xlinker /subsystem:console CMakeFiles/ppc2cpp.dir/src/cli/ppc2cpp.cpp.obj -o ppc2cpp.exe -Xlinker /MANIFEST:EMBED -Xlinker /implib:ppc2cpp.lib -Xlinker /pdb:ppc2cpp.pdb -Xlinker /version:0.0   ppc2cpp_core.lib  _deps/ninutils-build/dolrel.lib  _deps/ppcdisasm-cpp-build/ppcdisasm.lib  _deps/fmt-build/fmt.lib  D:/a/ppc2cpp/ppc2cpp/protobuf_x64-windows/lib/libprotobuf.lib  _deps/yaml-cpp-build/yaml-cpp.lib  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -loldnames  && cd ."
```

Full workflow logs: https://github.com/em-eight/ppc2cpp/actions/runs/6309753804/job/17130317792

This is my cmake file: https://github.com/em-eight/ppc2cpp/blob/5f201d86297284a90d7c11af518589ff1e566637/CMakeLists.txt

Looking at the build logs, the most suspicious things are `-DPROTOBUF_USE_DLLS` and `-D_DLL`. I found [this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/issues/19527) discussion on stack overflow taht suggested turning `Protobuf_USE_STATIC_LIBS` on, but it still doesn't work for me

Comment: It is requirement of Stack Overflow for **relevant code** and **error message** to be included into the **question post**, links are insufficient. See also [ask].

Comment: "Looking at the cmake build logs, it looks pretty apparent to me that both ppc2cpp_core.lib and ppc2cpp.exe use static linking" - Why do you think so? The filename `libprotobuf.lib` could correspond to a static library, but it also could correspond to an **export** library (for `.dll`).

Comment: Maybe? idk I'm a noob at windows. If that's the case, I'm screwed because I don't see any other .lib file in the distribution

Comment: " I don't see any other .lib file in the distribution" - If you have single `.dll` and single `.lib`, then they both related to the **shared** library. There is no static library in such distribution.

Comment: Yea, it seems like it. I'm going to have to talk to the protobuf people for this one.